# Overriding HostnameVerifier with Ion

Tags: android, networking, ion-koush, androidasync-koush

I am using Koushik Dutta's [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) networking library for Android. I need to override SSL checks for debugging purposes. I've found out how to set my own SSL context and TrustManager using:

```
Ion.getDefault(context).getHttpClient().getSSLSocketMiddleware().setSSLContext(mySslContext); 
Ion.getDefault(context).getHttpClient().getSSLSocketMiddleware().setTrustManagers(myTrustManager);
```

but I can't figure out how to pass in my own HostnameVerifier. With HttpsUrlConnection it was as simple as

```
 HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier(myHostNameVerifier);
```

Has anyone overridden SSL using ion? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a method to do this and sent a pull request to [AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync) on which [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) is dependent:

https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync/pull/34

It's merged now so a simple call to `setHostnameVerifier(HotstnameVerifier ver)` will do the trick! Example:

```
Ion.getDefault(context).getHttpClient().getSSLSocketMiddleware().setHostnameVerifier(myHostnameVerifier);
```